# Pagination in html table is not working

Tags: wp-query, pagination, list, table

I have a custom page template and I found a a PHP snippet that create a pagination in html table. But the code is not working properly.

UPDATE: I change the code. But still the code is not working correctly, when I click on the 2nd page, the 2nd page displayed a blank page only.

```
if (isset($_POST['list_position']) && $_POST['list_position'] != 'Select by Position'){
    $list_position= $_POST['list_position'];
    $result_position= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id, submit_time, last_name, first_name, middle_name, mobile_number, email, location, position, message, attachment_resume_id FROM resume_databank WHERE position= '" . $list_position . "' ORDER BY position ASC", OBJECT));

$rows_per_page = 3;
$current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

global $wp_rewrite;

$pagination_args = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => ceil(sizeof($result_position)/$rows_per_page),
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => false,
    'type' => 'plain',
);

if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
    $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1))) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']))
    $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));
    echo paginate_links($pagination_args);

$start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
$end = $start + $rows_per_page;
$end = (sizeof($result_position) < $end) ? sizeof($result_position) : $end;

    echo '<table id="paginate_result">';
        echo '<tr>';
        $optionId = 0;
        echo '<th>Submit Time</th>';
        echo '<th>Last Name</th>';
        echo '<th>First Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Middle Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Mobile Number</th>';
        echo '<th>Email</th>';
        echo '<th>Location</th>';
        echo '<th>Position</th>';
        echo '<th>Message</th>';
        echo '<th>Resume</th>';
        echo '<th>Processed?</th>';
        //foreach ($result_position as $record_s){
            for ($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i ) {
            $row = $result_position[$i];
            $optionId++;
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td id="submit_time">' . $result_position[0]->submit_time . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="last_name">' . $result_position[0]->last_name . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="first_name">' . $result_position[0]->first_name . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="middle_name">' . $result_position[0]->middle_name . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="mobile_number">' . $result_position[0]->mobile_number . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="email">' . $result_position[0]->email . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="location">' . $result_position[0]->location . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="position">' . $result_position[0]->position . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="message">' . $result_position[0]->message . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="resumeFile'.$optionId.'"><a href=' . wp_get_attachment_url($result_position[0]->attachment_resume_id) . '>Download Resume</a></td>';
            echo '<td id="radioOption><label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                      <input type="radio" id="processedOptionYes'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="Yes" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'Yes\')"/>
                      <label for="No">No</label>
                      <input type="radio" id="processedOptionNo'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="No" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'No\')"/></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Share your query with limit clause. Are you getting any error message when you access second page or empty result? If so, make sure you have result in the second page.

Comment: I dont get any error when I click on the 2nd page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get total and result array separately. Total is to create the page numbers and result array will give you limited data for each pages. Refer the below code.

```
if (isset($_POST['list_position']) && $_POST['list_position'] != 'Select by Position'){
    $list_position= $_POST['list_position'];
    $totalPosition= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(id) FROM resume_databank WHERE position= '" . $list_position . "' ORDER BY position ASC");
$rows_per_page = 3;
$current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

global $wp_rewrite;

$pagination_args = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => ceil(sizeof($totalPosition)/$rows_per_page),
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => false,
    'type' => 'plain',
);

if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
    $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1))) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']))
    $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));
    echo paginate_links($pagination_args);

$start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
$end = $start + $rows_per_page;
$end = ($totalPosition < $end) ? $totalPosition : $end;
$result_position= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id, submit_time, last_name, first_name, middle_name, mobile_number, email, location, position, message, attachment_resume_id FROM resume_databank WHERE position= '" . $list_position . "' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT $start,$end", OBJECT));

    echo '<table id="paginate_result">';
        echo '<tr>';
        $optionId = 0;
        echo '<th>Submit Time</th>';
        echo '<th>Last Name</th>';
        echo '<th>First Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Middle Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Mobile Number</th>';
        echo '<th>Email</th>';
        echo '<th>Location</th>';
        echo '<th>Position</th>';
        echo '<th>Message</th>';
        echo '<th>Resume</th>';
        echo '<th>Processed?</th>';
        //foreach ($result_position as $record_s){
            for ($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i ) {
            $row = $result_position[$i];
            $optionId++;
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td id="submit_time">' . $result_position[0]->submit_time . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="last_name">' . $result_position[0]->last_name . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="first_name">' . $result_position[0]->first_name . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="middle_name">' . $result_position[0]->middle_name . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="mobile_number">' . $result_position[0]->mobile_number . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="email">' . $result_position[0]->email . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="location">' . $result_position[0]->location . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="position">' . $result_position[0]->position . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="message">' . $result_position[0]->message . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="resumeFile'.$optionId.'"><a href=' . wp_get_attachment_url($result_position[0]->attachment_resume_id) . '>Download Resume</a></td>';
            echo '<td id="radioOption><label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                      <input type="radio" id="processedOptionYes'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="Yes" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'Yes\')"/>
                      <label for="No">No</label>
                      <input type="radio" id="processedOptionNo'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="No" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'No\')"/></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: the pagination is not displayed when I try your code

Comment: Replace `'total' => ceil(sizeof($totalPosition)/$rows_per_page)` with `'total' => ceil($totalPosition/$rows_per_page)` and try.

Comment: still when i click the link to the 2nd page, i get a blank page only

Comment: Come for the chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40254/karthikeyani

Comment: im in the chat room now

Comment: im sorry, im not get back to you, but current code that you suggest is not working